# What is the difference between var a = 5 and var a = Int(5)?

Tags: swift

Is there any difference literal value and integer literal value when declaring a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before optimization, yes, these are different. `var a = 5` is immediately optimized to give future references to `a` the value of 5. `var a = Int(5)` includes a function call to `SignedInteger.init`. You can see this by emitting the SIL:

```
echo "var x = 5" | swiftc -emit-sil -

// main
sil @main : $@convention(c) (Int32, UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>) -> Int32 {
bb0(%0 : $Int32, %1 : $UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>):
  alloc_global @$S4main1xSivp                     // id: %2
  %3 = global_addr @$S4main1xSivp : $*Int         // user: %6
  %4 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int64, 5          // user: %5
  %5 = struct $Int (%4 : $Builtin.Int64)          // user: %6
  store %5 to %3 : $*Int                          // id: %6
  %7 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int32, 0          // user: %8
  %8 = struct $Int32 (%7 : $Builtin.Int32)        // user: %9
  return %8 : $Int32                              // id: %9
} // end sil function 'main'
```

---

```
echo "var x = Int(5)" | swiftc -emit-sil -

// main
sil @main : $@convention(c) (Int32, UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>) -> Int32 {
bb0(%0 : $Int32, %1 : $UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>):
  alloc_global @$S4main1xSivp                     // id: %2
  %3 = global_addr @$S4main1xSivp : $*Int         // user: %11
  %4 = metatype $@thin Int.Type
  %5 = metatype $@thick Int.Type                  // user: %11
  %6 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int64, 5          // user: %7
  %7 = struct $Int (%6 : $Builtin.Int64)          // user: %9
  %8 = alloc_stack $Int                           // users: %9, %12, %11
  store %7 to %8 : $*Int                          // id: %9
  // function_ref SignedInteger<>.init<A>(_:)
  %10 = function_ref @$SSZss17FixedWidthIntegerRzrlEyxqd__cSzRd__lufC : $@convention(method) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : FixedWidthInteger, τ_0_0 : SignedInteger><τ_1_0 where τ_1_0 : BinaryInteger> (@in τ_1_0, @thick τ_0_0.Type) -> @out τ_0_0 // user: %11
  %11 = apply %10<Int, Int>(%3, %8, %5) : $@convention(method) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : FixedWidthInteger, τ_0_0 : SignedInteger><τ_1_0 where τ_1_0 : BinaryInteger> (@in τ_1_0, @thick τ_0_0.Type) -> @out τ_0_0
  dealloc_stack %8 : $*Int                        // id: %12
  %13 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int32, 0         // user: %14
  %14 = struct $Int32 (%13 : $Builtin.Int32)      // user: %15
  return %14 : $Int32                             // id: %15
} // end sil function 'main'
```

---

However, once it's optimized (add `-O` to the `swiftc` lines), they're (basically) identical to the `var a = 5` version:

```
// main
sil @main : $@convention(c) (Int32, UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>) -> Int32 {
bb0(%0 : $Int32, %1 : $UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>):
  alloc_global @$S4main1xSivp                     // id: %2
  %3 = global_addr @$S4main1xSivp : $*Int         // user: %6
  %4 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int64, 5          // user: %5
  %5 = struct $Int (%4 : $Builtin.Int64)          // user: %6
  store %5 to %3 : $*Int                          // id: %6
  %7 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int32, 0          // user: %8
  %8 = struct $Int32 (%7 : $Builtin.Int32)        // user: %9
  return %8 : $Int32                              // id: %9
} // end sil function 'main'
```

The latter will emit a huge amount of additional SIL for protocol witnesses that aren't actually used, but this won't impact the final binary.

You can explore the final assembly output with godbolt:

- https://godbolt.org/z/NCCEaD  // var a = 5
- https://godbolt.org/z/UWM9ta  // var a = 5 optimized
- https://godbolt.org/z/-Ki_yk  // var a = Int(5)
- https://godbolt.org/z/zvWK0S  // var a = Int(5) optimized

As you'll note, the optimized versions are exactly identical.

In practice, it really doesn't matter. It is common style in Swift to omit the type, but there are many cases where it's needed, such as for UInt or Int64 types, and even Int() can be useful for clarity sometimes.

Whether you write it `var a: UInt = 5` or `var a = UInt(5)` is just style, even though they lead to slightly different unoptimized output. Rest assured that the optimizer will easily fix up any of these approaches for you, and just write in the style that is most clear to your problem. But when in doubt, leave it out. That's the typical preference in Swift.

Answer (score 6):

```
var a = 5
```

This creates an `Int` variable with value of `5`.  Swift infers the type of `a` from the integer literal.  `Int` is the default type for an integer literal when no other information is available.

```
var a = Int(5)
```

This calls an initializer on `Int` with an `Int` value `5` that was created like the above value.

To find out more information about this initializer, change the statement to:

```
var a = Int.init(5)
```

and then <kbd>option</kbd>-click on `init`.

You will see:

> **Summary**
>
> Creates a new instance from the given integer.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> `convenience init<T>(_ source: T) where T : BinaryInteger`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Use this initializer to convert from another integer type when you
>   know the value is within the bounds of this type. Passing a value that
>   can’t be represented in this type results in a runtime error.

So, you are unnecessarily calling an initializer for `Int` with a value that is already inferred to be an `Int`.  As @RobNapier explains in his [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54025342/1630618), the extra call will be cleaned up by the optimizer.  But I think, why bother?

If you want to note the type, you can explicitly type the variable:

```
var a: Int = 5
```

but letting Swift infer the type:

```
var a = 5
```

is the preferred way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
let a = 5
print(a)            // 5
print(type(of: a))  // Int
let b = Int(5)
print(b)            // 5
print(type(of: b))  // Int
```

You simply use the Int class constructor. In your second way it's implicit. Pick your first option.

Comment: Both are same object type of int?

Comment: @John yes, that's the purpose of type(of:) function printed in example.

Answer (score 2):

Swift uses type inference and integer literals are inferred the type `Int`, so the type of `a` in `let a = 5` will be `Int`. Hence, passing an integer literal to the initialiser of `Int`  has no other effect, so your two examples achieve the same results.